# Collision isn't consistent

Tags: c++, sdl, collision-detection, collision, entitymanager

I'm currently developing a Mario Bros copy using SDL for a Project, I've just implemented Collision though I've ran into something strange where the Collision will sometimes work and sometimes won't each time I load the game. These gif's pretty much explain what I mean:
[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the Collision works sometimes but each time I reload the game, the results change and I actually have no idea why. There is also other strange things that happen with for example the Red Borders you can see surrounding each entity, that's their collision box but sometimes as you can see in the gif's, some blocks don't have the collision box showing despite having collision. I did also in the past have blocks sometimes not even rendering though that hasn't happened for awhile.

How I'm loading the map is from a txt file that looks like this:
[image]

That is then loaded in using my LevelMap Class:

```
bool LevelMap::CreateMap(std::string path)
{
std::vector<std::string> lines = std::vector<std::string>();
std::fstream file;
file.open(path, std::fstream::in);


char text[256];
std::string currentLine;
while (!file.eof())
{
    file.getline(text, 256);
    currentLine = text;
    currentLine.erase(std::remove_if(currentLine.begin(), currentLine.end(), 
std::isspace), currentLine.end()); //Removes Spaces from String

    //Checks if String is at correct Width
    if (currentLine.size() != mapWidth)
    {
        std::cout << "Map Has Incorrect Width!" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    lines.push_back(currentLine);
}

// Loop over every tile position,
for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++)
    {
        char tileType = lines.at(y)[x]; //Gets Each Tile Value

        Entity* entity = LoadEntity(tileType, x, y);
        if (entity != nullptr)
        {
            entityManager->AddEntity(entity);
        }
    }
}

return true;
}

Entity* LevelMap::LoadEntity(char tileType, int x, int y)
{
x *= (SCREEN_WIDTH / mapWidth);
y *= (SCREEN_WIDTH / mapWidth);

switch (tileType)
{
    //Creates Block
    case '1':
        return CreateBlock(Vector2D(x, y));
    break;

    //Creates Pipe facing Left
    case '2':
        return CreatePipe(Vector2D(x, y), FACING::FACING_RIGHT);
    break;

    //Creates Pipe facing Right
    case '3':
        return CreatePipe(Vector2D(x, y), FACING::FACING_LEFT);
    break;

    //Creates Player
    case 'P':
        return CreatePlayer(Vector2D(x, y));
    break;

    default:
        return nullptr;
    break;

}
}

Entity* LevelMap::CreateBlock(Vector2D position)
{
    Block* block = new Block(renderer, position, this);
    return block;
}

Entity* LevelMap::CreatePipe(Vector2D position, FACING direction)
{
    Pipe* pipe = new Pipe(renderer, position, direction, this);
    return pipe;
}

Entity* LevelMap::CreatePlayer(Vector2D position)
{
    Player* player = new Player(renderer, position, this);
    return player;
}
```

It basically gets each number in that .txt file, uses that to create a Entity using the LoadEntity function which returns a Entity based on the number. This Entity is then added to an Vector within another class I have called EntityManager which is used to handle all the entities in the game.

So that's loading my Map. My Collision Code looks like this:

```
void Collision::Update(Rect2D boundingBox)
{
    this->boundingBox = boundingBox;
}

void Collision::DrawBoundingBox(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
SDL_Rect* rect = new SDL_Rect();
rect->x = boundingBox.X;
rect->y = boundingBox.Y;
rect->w = boundingBox.width;
rect->h = boundingBox.height;

SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, rect);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);
}

bool Collision::Intersects(Entity* entity)
{
Rect2D entityBoundingBox = entity->GetCollsion()->GetCollisionBox();

//Checks if two rectangles intersect 
if(boundingBox.X + boundingBox.width < entityBoundingBox.X  || 
entityBoundingBox.X + entityBoundingBox.width < boundingBox.X || 
boundingBox.Y + boundingBox.height < entityBoundingBox.Y || 
entityBoundingBox.Y + entityBoundingBox.height < boundingBox.Y)
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
}
```

The Update Function updates the bounding box surrounding each entity, the DrawBoundBox function renders the red border you see in the gif's and then the Intersects Function is used to check if the Entity calling the function is intersecting with the passed in Entity's Collision.

That's essentially the main parts, I'll explain more if needed but for the Collision's Update, It's called within the Entity classes Update function:

```
void Entity::CollisionUpdate()
{
    Rect2D boundingBox = Rect2D(position.X, position.Y, sprite.width, 
sprite.height);
    collsion->Update(boundingBox); //Updates the Collsion Position
}
```

And the Entity's Update and Render is called by the Update and Render functions within the Entity Manager I mentioned:

```
void EntityManager::Update(float deltaTime, SDL_Event e)
{
if(!entities.empty())
{
    //Runs the Update function of all entities and adds Entites that need to be deleted to a list
    for(const auto entity : entities)
    {       
        if(entity.second->ShouldDestroy())
        {
            toDeleteEntities.push_back(entity.second);
        }

        //std::cout << entity.second->GetTag() << std::endl;
        entity.second->Update(deltaTime, e);
    }

    //Removes entities that need to be deleted
    for(int i = 0; i < toDeleteEntities.size(); i++)
    {
        RemoveEntity(toDeleteEntities[i], i);
    }
}
}

void EntityManager::Render()
{
if(!entities.empty())
{
    for(const auto entity : entities)
    {
        entity.second->Render();
    }
}
}
```

and then Finally the Entity Manager's Update and Render functions get called by the LevelMap.

Sorry for the long paragraph of text. I'm hoping that's enough detail for someone to figure out what's wrong and why this is happening, I'd very much appreciate the help. And if you need any more details then please just ask.

**EDIT**
CollisionUpdate() is called within the Entity's Update Function which as mentioned is called by the EntityManager:

```
void Entity::Update(float deltaTime, SDL_Event e)
{
//Screen Warps
if (position.X <= 0 - GetTexture()->GetWidth())
{
    position.X = SCREEN_WIDTH - GetTexture()->GetWidth();
}
else if (position.X >= SCREEN_WIDTH)
{
    position.X = 0 + GetTexture()->GetWidth();
}

if (collsion != nullptr)
{
    CollisionUpdate();
}
}
```

Also the Intersects function is called within both the Player and Enemies Update Function:

```
void Player::CollisionUpdate()
{
Entity::CollisionUpdate();

std::vector<Entity*> entities = map->GetEntityManager()->GetEntities("");
for (int i = 0; i < entities.size(); i++)
{
    if (entities[i]->GetCollsion() != nullptr)
    {
        //What Player Collides With
        if(collsion->Intersects(entities[i]))
        {
            if (entities[i]->GetTag() == "Block")
            {
                SetGravity(false);
            }
            else
            {
                SetGravity(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The GetEntities function is part of the EntityManager class and it will get a Vector of all the entities that have a passed in tag, so Block's will have a "Block" tag and if you pass that into the function then it will only return a function with blocks.
This is the GetEntities function is you want to see:

```
std::vector<Entity*> EntityManager::GetEntities(std::string tag)
{
std::vector<Entity*> entityList;

//If Tag is not empty, find certain entities with tag
if (tag != "")
{
    for (const auto entity : entities)
    {
        if (entity.second->GetTag() == tag)
        {
            entityList.push_back(entity.second);
        }
    }
}
else if (tag == "") //Else find all entities
{
    for (const auto entity : entities)
    {
        entityList.push_back(entity.second);
    }
}

return entityList;
}
```

Comment: You should post only relevant code. Where do you call `CollisionUpdate` or `Intersects` for example?

Comment: There is a memory leak in your code, watch out

Comment: I believe the Collision Code and EntityManager code is relevant, also i made a change to my post mentioning the CollisionUpdate and Intersects

Comment: Use the debugger to read individual values on runtime. This is in my opinion the most sensible approach.

Comment: Fun question - what happens when your velocity along one axis is larger than the size of its collision box along that axis?   There is a reason that one should use vector math to determine if a starting and ending point intersected a line.  I see no such math in the above code.

Comment: Uhh, I have no such maths XD. I wasn't aware that I had to do that though truthfully collision is completely new to me

Comment: While revelant, gifs show that this is not the cause of the problem here.

Comment: Agreed - this case feels more like a list management or math error in collision detection itself.  Placing an object on the "ground" can also be an interesting issue that is easy to mess up.  You end up getting things stuck inside collision or shake/bouncing down to the ground.  Might be useful to debug a turtle and see when gravity is enabled/disabled, and perhaps check what is happening when it is inside another collision already.

Comment: Interesting fact - you are falling through the ground when your turtle's box's X coordinates exactly match that of the ground box you are on top of.  Perhaps check your collision detection for when the X positions are exactly equal.

Comment: It may be the Collision Code. I outputted something to say when Gravity was set to true (So when they're not colliding with ablock) and it seems that gravity is being set to true and then back to false every frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. It was the way I was checking collision against entities that was causing the problem. What I had was a for loop that would loop through each entity and check if a entity collided with them, if it did then it would disable Gravity.

The problem is the for loop would then immediately go onto the next entity and check collision against that. So it would get that the entity was colliding with a block and would stop Gravity, but then it would go onto a next entity in the list, see we're not colliding with it and then enable Gravity, despite still colliding with the same block.

So instead of just checking collision against a single entity such as the block under Mario:
[image]

It instead checked for Collision against all of this:
[image]

And because we're not currently colliding with all those others blocks, it enables Gravity again.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your return statements around in your collision function. You seem to be returning false when they are colliding instead or returning true.

Comment: If I change them around then it just makes the entities float as they don't have Gravity

Answer (score 0):

```
if(boundingBox.X + boundingBox.width < entityBoundingBox.X  || 
   entityBoundingBox.X + entityBoundingBox.width < boundingBox.X || 
   boundingBox.Y + boundingBox.height < entityBoundingBox.Y || 
   entityBoundingBox.Y + entityBoundingBox.height < boundingBox.Y)


 //                        X  Y  W  H                      
 let boundingBox        = {10,10,10,10}
 let entityBoundingBox  = {10,20,10,10}

10 + 10 < 10 == false
10 + 10 < 10 == false
10 + 10 < 20 == false
20 + 10 < 10 == false
```

This returns true in your logic, meaning collision.  These do not collide.  Pretty sure your collision logic is not correct.

Comment: It was pretty much some code I randomly got off the internet since I couldn't remember the algorithm exactly.

Comment: Then go search a bit harder.  Right now, your logic is off.  I'm honestly amazed that your code is working at all without turtles floating just above the ground while gravity turns on and off to get them stuck into the ground.

Comment: If coding was easy, everyone would do it :)

Comment: I quickly looked up this and used the algorithm found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/kab/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection

That seems to work though I'm still having the entities falling through the ground. Also as I mentioned in a comment on my main post, it seems that gravity is being set to true and then being set to false each frame, no matter if the Entity is colliding with a block or not.

Comment: Yea, it seems it does collide with the block correctly and then disable Gravity but then Gravity is instantly enabled again despite colliding with the block